# Creating a Chart with SwiftCharts

Tags: swift, charts, swiftcharts

I am new to SwiftCharts so I am still trying to understand how it works. I wanted to draw a cubic line chart, however, to no success.

As far as I understand from [this](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/blob/master/Examples/Examples/CubicLinesExample.swift) example, the view that would contain the chart should be of class "Chart". However, as you can see from the screenshot, I cannot find such class in the drop-down list.

[image: Screenshot]

Could you please tell me how to proceed in order to draw cubic line chart using SwiftCharts?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but will answer anyway: The view has to be of class `ChartBaseView`, not chart! `Chart` is just a wrapper (not a view). Here is a snippet for autolayout: https://gist.github.com/i-schuetz/f6e285eb0c86bb831510

Comment: ChartBaseView seems not to exist for me.